# Stretching element of the site

Tags: html, css

Have a look at mockup image

[image]

The site have a fixed content width. I need elements inside a red area to be stretched, depending on the screen width. So in case it's like on the image, green and blue stripes should go till the end of the screen. If screen is wider, site content area( that is inside the vertical red lines ) will be the same. But blue and green lines will stretch more, to reach the sites left and right side.

I was going to implement it using absolute positioning. But I need to know the width of the block. And as it can be different I do not know how to do it, except for using javascript. but I'd like to use html and css only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but the coolest of all is using the `before` & `after` pseudo elements to fill in the edges.

```css
.container {
    width: 1200px; /* whatever... */
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    background: #000; /* whatever... */
}

.header:before, .header:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #000; /* whatever... */
    top:0 ; bottom: 0; width: 999em;
}

.header:before {
    right: 100%;
}
.header:after {
    left: 100%;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bnket/

---

Check out this cool article by Chris Coyer: [**Full Browser Width Bars**](http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/).

Comment: I need things to work in ie8+. Is there any way to make it work with ie8+? Sorry, don't have enough repoutation to vote you up. Will vote up as soon as have enough rep.

Comment: @webbyalena - This works perfectly in IE8.

Comment: Ok, I just tried in ie tester. If it works fine, I will accept your answer as the right one. The solution overall looks great!

Answer (score 0):

using css assume your center content is 800px in width..

You would add 800 plus the width of the stripes and asign fixed left & right
 thats about it.

This is all i can provide due to the lack of a jsfiddle